# Where can I learn and understand the complete workings of HTTP headers, so I can implement my own?

Tags: specifications, http

I am looking to learn how to properly use, and implement, HTTP headers. What is the best resource or set of guidelines that I can use? ( especially ranges to detect download managers, etc) ?

Comment: Just curious: Why are you interested in creating your own HTTP headers? Curl or its equivalent not an option in your language?

Comment: @TheLQ, maybe he needs to add webserver functionality to an app?

Answer (score 8):

Well your first stop should probably be [RFC2616: Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html).

The [Range](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35) section is used to request specific areas of a file; with responses providing [Content-Range](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.16) declarations to provide this feature.